# Usage: "EncryptUtil encrypt" password password : The clear text password to encrypt

Tags: java, mysql, encryption, passwords

I am getting the following error when trying to connect to my sql database from my java program. Where does this error come from? I'm literally importing only these packages:

```
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
```

How can I skip or fix these error?

Comment: What kind of errors are you getting?

Comment: Show full text of error and yours code

Comment: This is the error: Usage: "EncryptUtil encrypt" password
     password : The clear text password to encrypt.  Im only trying to connect to mysql db:  String myDriver = "org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver";
      String myUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/tweetsDB";
      Class.forName(myDriver);
     Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(myUrl, "root", "student");

Answer (score 0):

Your Question is not clear.You will Try this if you have missing some package

```
Right click on project - >BuildPath - >Configure BuildPath - >Libraries tab - >
```

then  Double click on JRE SYSTEM LIBRARY - >Then select alternate JRE